# Google Geocoding API rejects my requests

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-geocoding-api

I have a screen with a map and an edit text where the user can type a location. The maps are from Mapbox but its geocoding is not good enough so I want to use one from Google.
As the user types in he should see a list of suggested places based on the address he is typing. When he clicks on any of them, a pin should be drop on the map. 
I created a project in the developer's console, generated an api key restricting it Android devices. The key is used when sending requests.
I defined a Retrofit interface like so

```
public interface GeocodingApi {

    String PATH = "maps/api/geocode/json";
    String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    String KEY_KEY = "key";
    String KEY_LANGUAGE = "language";


    @GET(PATH)
    Single<GeocodingResponse> getPlaces(
            @Query(value = KEY_ADDRESS, encoded = true) String address,
            @Query(KEY_KEY) String apiKey,
            @Query(KEY_LANGUAGE) String language
    );
}
```

And then I make a request like so

```
disposable = getGeocodingApi()
                .getPlaces(addressName, getApiKey(), getLanguage())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(
                        response -> {
                            if (!"OK".equals(response.getStatus())) {
                                final String errorMessage = response.getErrorMessage();
                                if (errorMessage != null) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, errorMessage);
                                }
                                return;
                            }
                            final List<AddressResponse> addresses = response.getAddresses();
                            for (final AddressResponse address : addresses) {
                                final String formattedAddress = address.getFormattedAddress();
                                if (formattedAddress != null) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, formattedAddress);
                                }
                                final GeometryResponse geometry = address.getGeometry();
                                final double lat = geometry.getLocation().getLat();
                                final double lon = geometry.getLocation().getLon();
                                Log.i(TAG, "Lat: " + lat + ", lon: " + lon + "\n");
                            }
                        },
                        error -> Log.e(TAG, error.toString())
                );
```

But what I get is an error saying that my IP address, site or device is not authorized to use this API key. Why is that? I specified my app's package name with its SHA1 fingerprint when generating the api key. 
Can anyone please help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by removing the api key restriction in the developer console. You can either create a new key without any restrictions or change your current key's restriction and wait for up to 5 minutes for setting to take effect.

Comment: You are using Places API web service, the only supported restrictions for web services are IP address restrictions. You can check which type of restriction is valid for each Google Maps API at https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem